# An ordering of $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ which makes it an Archimedean field.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, field-theory, rational-functions

The following question is from one of my homework:

> Show that the field $\mathbb{Q}(X)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$ in one indeterminate $X$, admits the structure of an ordered field having the Archimedean property. What can you say about $\mathbb{Q}(X, Y) ?$

My interpretation of the question is that it asks to define an valid ordering on $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ which has the Archimedean property. I am unable to find such an ordering. I could find some orderings on $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ (for example, to define $f>g$ if $f-g$ has both the numerator and denominator having positive leading coefficients) but all of those failed to satisfy the Archimedean property. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider evaluating the functions at some fixed value of $x$. For which $x$ is this operation injective?

Comment: Ah so choosing $x$ to be a transcendental number works @Karl! What about the other part? I guess a similar process gives an affirmative answer? @Karl

Comment: Ok, I guess the following works. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be a Transcendental number. Then we can define the orderings as, 
for $Q(X)$: $f>g \iff f(\alpha) > g(\alpha)$
for $Q(X,Y)$: $f>g \iff f(\alpha,\alpha) > g(\alpha,\alpha)$

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for $\mathbb Q(X,Y)$ because you can have $f(\alpha,\alpha) = g(\alpha,\alpha)$ without having $f=g$.

Comment: But maybe you could try to have an [algebraically independent](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence) pair $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ of transcendental numbers and then define $f$ to be positive when $f(\alpha,\beta) > 0$

Comment: @kahen I get it, Thanks!